# Using Google Appscript/HTML service to upload attachment to Google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am currently using appscript with HTML service to populate a spreadsheet and upload a couple of files to a google drive. These files are images for which urls are not image links in google drive. Image links are only usable with files on google sites. So I need to convert this from uploading to drive to uploading to a folder on a google sites file cabinet page.
 All of the info I have found re: attachments to google sites are using the UI app which I am not interested in. I want to use the HTML service. Here is what I have which is fully functional:

**Server .gs**

```js
var dropBoxId = "blablahbalh"; // Drive ID of 'dropbox' folder
var logSheetId = "blahblahbalh"; // Drive ID of log spreadsheet

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myForm.html');
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    // Create a file in Drive from the one provided in the form
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dropBoxId);
   var blob = formObject.myFile;
   var blob2 = formObject.myFile2;
   var file = folder.createFile(blob);
   var file2 = folder.createFile(blob2);
   file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.myName);

   // Open the log and record the new file name, URL and name from form
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSheetId);
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   sheet.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), file2.getName(),
   file2.getUrl(), formObject.myName, formObject.actor_unions,   formObject.actor_email, formObject.actor_phone, formObject.actor_website]);

// Return the new file Drive URL so it can be put in the web app output
return file.getUrl();
} catch (error) {
 return error.toString();
  }
 }
```

**HTML**

```html
<form id="myForm">
 <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your full name..."/>
  <input type="text" name="actor_unions" placeholder="Union affiliations..."/>
 <input type="text" name="actor_email" placeholder="email Address..."/>
 <input type="text" name="actor_phone" placeholder="phone number..."/>
 <input type="text" name="actor_website" placeholder="Website..."/>
 <input name="myFile" type="file" />
 <input name="myFile2" type="file" />
 <input type="button" value="Submit"
  onclick="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" />
 </form>

  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
   function updateUrl(url) {
       var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Upload successful!</a>';
  }
  function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
 </script>

 <style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
 </style>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To ensure your question has more visibility, please [edit] it and add the related language tags (HTML and, I think, Javascript). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I used the tags most appropriate to the question since it has less to do with language specific syntax and more to do with Google specific functioning.

Comment: Sandy thanks for your input. Yes I looked at that, You posted info for creating an attachment that is a link to another resource. I need to use a html form to actually upload the files and upon success to write the URL of the uploaded files to a spreadsheet along with other gathered info.

Comment: The code you posted seems to have all the parts needed to do what you want.  You will need to provide more information.  Do you know how to use `console.log('message to print')` in the browser, and `Logger.log('my variable name: ' + variableName);` in the script code to debug the code?  Up to what point is the code working?  [Apps Script documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)  I deleted my last comment to save space.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to add an attachment to a specific folder on a File Cabinet type page of a Google Site using AppScript - [SitesApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app) does not expose any methods to work with File Cabinet folders in any way.

If you are OK with just uploading a file as attachment to a specific site page without putting it in a folder, then the code for that is pretty straight-forward:

```
function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    var blob = formObject.myFile;
    var site = SitesApp.getSite("your-site-name-as-in-url");
    // if your site is under a Google Apps hosted domain, then instead use
    // var site = SitesApp.getSite("your-domain", "your-site-name-as-in-url");
    var page = site.getChildByName("name-of-page-as-in-its-url");
    var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(blob);
    return attachment.getUrl();
  }
  catch(error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't work with my code. Tried your code alone. Execution transcript:

` [16-03-28 18:43:44:775 EDT] Starting execution
[16-03-28 18:43:44:841 EDT] SitesApp.getSite([https://sites.google.com/a/nyu.edu/lttest4]) [0.059 seconds]
[16-03-28 18:43:44:843 EDT] Execution succeeded [0.061 seconds total runtime] `code`

Comment: Did you change the `var site` declaration as per comment in my code, since you are on a hosted Google Apps domain?  In your case that line should be: `var site = SitesApp.getSite("nyu.edu", "lttest4");`  Did you also spot and correct the typo in my code? The `var page` line was incorrect; it should be: `var page = site.getChildByName("name-of-your-site-page-as-in-its-url");`

Comment: PS: since your code is using try/catch, no error will be displayed in the Execution Transcript - you have to log it yourself. What eaxctly did the error message say?

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. I wasn't having an issue connectingto the site. The error I am getting is:  

` Cannot call method "addHostedAttachment" of null`  

It looks like the form is not passing the attachment.

Comment: The form definitely works when used to upload to drive.

Comment: OK so I renamed the HTML form and now it works. Will post final code